# How do I deserialize JSON in C# with Newtonsoft

Tags: python, c#, .net, windows, performance

I have a snippet of a code written in python which I have to rewrite to C# with the help of Newtonsoft JSON

```
def getconfig():
    with open("config.json") as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())
```

and I have to be able to access the elements of JSON in the code just as it's shown in this snippet

```
def getcaptcha(proxy):
    while(True):
        ret = s.get("{}{}&pageurl={}"
            .format(getconfig()['host'], getconfig()['key'], getconfig()['googlekey'], getconfig()['pageurl'])).text
```

So far I've come up with this idea:

```
public bool GetConfig()
        {
            JObject config = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("path/config.json"));

            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("path/config.json"))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                JObject getConfig = (JObject) JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

but it doesn't seem to be working since I can't access  it in further code as

```
GetConfig()['host']
```

for example. I can't even Console.WriteLine my JSON

Comment: in C#, strings are enclosed with double quotes, like "host", not 'host'. You should get a compilation error if you  try 'host' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define your `GetConfig` function as:

```cs
public JObject GetConfig()
{
    return JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("path/config.json"));
}
```

then, call that function and access elements defined in the json file like:

```cs
JObject config = GetConfig();
string host = config.SelectToken("host").Value<string>();
string key = config.SelectToken("key").Value<string>();
```